# mostly issues with zend package while installing pecl svm on mac with php 7.1

Tags: php, svm, libsvm

I need to install SVM classifier on my PHP server(php 7.1). I have installed libsvm and other package required for `pecl SVM`. I am a mac user and have following steps-

1. brew install gnuplot
2. brew install libsvm

This install libsvm 3.22, Now,  i tried to install pecl  svm classifier by-
`sudo pecl install -f svm`but this command 5 warnings and 20 errors like below-

1. warning: implicit declaration of function 'MAKE_STD_ZVAL' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] `MAKE_STD_ZVAL(line_array);`
2. error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
                       `ZVAL_STRING(pz_label, label, 1);`
3. note: macro 'ZVAL_STRING' defined here `#define ZVAL_STRING(z, s) do {`
4. error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZVAL_STRING'
                       `ZVAL_STRING(pz_label, label, 1);`
5. error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
                               `ZVAL_STRING(pz_idx, idx, 1);`
6. note: macro 'ZVAL_STRING' defined here
   `#define ZVAL_STRING(z, s) do {`
7. error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZVAL_STRING'
                               `ZVAL_STRING(pz_idx, idx, 1);`
8. error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
                               `ZVAL_STRING(pz_value, value, 1);`
9. warning: implicit declaration of function 'FREE_ZVAL' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                               `FREE_ZVAL(pz_idx);`
10. too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
                 `zend_hash_get_current_data(Z_ARRVAL_P(array), (void **) &ppzval) == SUCCESS;`
11. error: use of undeclared identifier 'zend_hash_get_current_data'; did you mean 'zend_hash_get_current_data_ex'?
                 `zend_hash_get_current_data(Z_ARRVAL_P(array), (void **) &ppzval) == SUCCESS;`
12. warning: comparison of function 'zend_hash_get_current_data_ex' equal to a null pointer is always false [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
                 `zend_hash_get_current_data(Z_ARRVAL_P(array), (void **) &ppzval) == SUCCESS;`

and so on, all the problems are related to zend_*.

> How can i install SVM correctly in my local System. 
>   What's wrong with system or pecl svm package? What should I do to get SVM?